# Shall Angular libraries be written in typescript or compiled to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

I am developing a library which will be installed as Angular module via npm. The library has been written in typescript. Until Angular 5.0.0 everything worked like a charm, however since 5.0 users started to receive following errors:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/mypackage/index.ts Module build failed:
>   Error: /node_modules/mypackage/index.ts is not part of
>   the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for
>   details.

As a workaround, I can add include path to the file in tsconfig.json. My question is whether I should continue providing a library in a typescript or shall I compile it to JS and ship as compiled package and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practices for publishing typescript code into npm is written at : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

TL:DR - ship js along with proper type definition.

It'll allow any js consumer can use lib, and ts users can benefit from types. There are very rare cases you'd like to ship ts code as-is such as allow fine-grained compilation from user level code to node modules.

Comment: I agree, I have a few projects on github.com, where you can see how I setup typescript to allow distribution via npm (e.g. https://github.com/wzr1337/rsiServer). I ship source maps with the modules because I think it makes debugging so much easier for everyone.